# Data deletion using 'If' function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible in Excel as using `vlookup` or `if` function that if data is 0 then that row should be deleted? For example:

```
If cell B1=0 then DELETE cell b1, and if cell B1=1 then UNCHANGED
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is not a formula/script writing service. Usually we expect to see some work on your part before answers are given. Please tell us what you have research and attempted so far. If you need help writing a better question, please take a look at ***[ask]***.

Answer (score 0):

Try the macro *Main()*:

```
Sub MAIN()
   Dim rng As Range, v As Variant
   Set rng = Range("B1")
   v = 0
   Call RowKiller(rng, v)
End Sub

Sub RowKiller(r As Range, v As Variant)
   If r.Value = v Then
      r.EntireRow.Delete
   End If
End Sub
```